# Is this usage of exec() safe when using escapeshellarg()?

Tags: php, security, exec

I have this code :

```
$path = "/somedirectory/$user";
echo exec('du -s '.escapeshellarg($path));
```

This code is used to check how many space the user use in his directory. The $user value can be any alphanumeric value and ".-"

Is it safe to use it ?

Answer (score 2):

`escapeshellarg` ensures that the value is interpreted as a single, plain shell argument without further shell expansion (e. g., no `` ​`…`​ ``, `$(…)`, `${…}`, etc.). That means that any value in `$path` is passed as is as a single argument to `du`.

However, as already mentioned, it does not prevent from passing arguments that may be  malicious when interpreted by the executable.

Answer (score 1):

This is safe in the sense that it won't run arbitrary commands, but depending on how `$user` gets set, `..` could sneak in there, which would let whoever is looking at this to see the size of the `/` directory, which may or may not be of concern to you.

Answer (score 0):

Safe if only your exec does not rely on any $user related commands.

For example, $user . "/du -s " is absolutely unsafe.